# How to execute a full text search using entity framework 6

Tags: entity-framework, full-text-search

I have the query:

```
var query = DataContext.Fotos.Where(x => x.Pesquisa.Contais("myTerm")
```

The SQL generated is:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM Fotos AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[Pesquisa] LIKE N'%mytem%'
```

But I need to use:

```
SELECT 
...
FROM Fotos AS [Extent1]
WHERE CONTAINS ([Extent1].[Pesquisa], 'my term')
```

How to execute a full text search using entity framework 6?

Comment: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/298/implementing-sql-server-full-text-search-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-with-entity-framework

Answer (score 27):

Seems that Entity Framework 6 does not support full text search, but there is a workaround with interceptors.

http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch

**Update** Link doesn't work so here is the original content:

> Microsoft TSQL supports full-text query by means of predicates
>   (CONTAINS and FREETEXT)
>
> For example, you have table Notes
>
> ```
> Create table Notes (
>     Id int Identity not null,
>     NoteText text 
> )
>
> CREATE FULLTEXT CATALOG [Notes Data]
> ```
>
> When you search this table for records containing word 'John', you
>   need to issue
>
> ```
> SELECT TOP (10) 
> * from gps.NOTES
> WHERE contains(NoteText, '(john)')
> ```
>
> Unfortunately, Enity framework does not support full-text search
>   predicates still. For EFv6, you can make a workaround using
>   interception.
>
> The idea is to wrap search text with some magic word during inside
>   plain String.Contains code and use interceptor to unwrap it right
>   before sql is executed in SqlCommand.
>
> To start, lets create the interceptor class:
>
> ```
> public class FtsInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
> {
>     private const string FullTextPrefix = "-FTSPREFIX-";
>     public static string Fts(string search)
>     {
>     return string.Format("({0}{1})", FullTextPrefix, search);
>     }
>     public void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
>     {
>     }
>     public void NonQueryExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
>     {
>     }
>     public void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
>     {
>         RewriteFullTextQuery(command);
>     }
>     public void ReaderExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
>     {
>     }
>     public void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
>     {
>         RewriteFullTextQuery(command);
>     }
>     public void ScalarExecuted(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
>     {
>     }
>     public static void RewriteFullTextQuery(DbCommand cmd)
>     {
>         string text = cmd.CommandText;
>         for (int i = 0; i < cmd.Parameters.Count; i++)
>         {
>             DbParameter parameter = cmd.Parameters[i];
>             if (parameter.DbType.In(DbType.String, DbType.AnsiString, DbType.StringFixedLength, DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength))
>             {
>                 if (parameter.Value == DBNull.Value)
>                     continue;
>                 var value = (string)parameter.Value;
>                 if (value.IndexOf(FullTextPrefix) >= 0)
>                 {
>                     parameter.Size = 4096;
>                     parameter.DbType = DbType.AnsiStringFixedLength;
>                     value = value.Replace(FullTextPrefix, ""); // remove prefix we added n linq query
>                     value = value.Substring(1, value.Length - 2); // remove %% escaping by linq translator from string.Contains to sql LIKE
>                     parameter.Value = value;
>                     cmd.CommandText = Regex.Replace(text,
>                     string.Format(
>                     @"\[(\w*)\].\[(\w*)\]\s*LIKE\s*@{0}\s?(?:ESCAPE
>                     N?'~')",parameter.ParameterName),
>                     string.Format(@"contains([$1].[$2], @{0})",parameter.ParameterName));
>                     if (text == cmd.CommandText)
>                         throw new Exception("FTS was not replaced on: " + text);
>                     text = cmd.CommandText;
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> I used extension function In that can be defined like this:
>
> ```
> static class LanguageExtensions
> {
>     public static bool In<T>(this T source, params T[] list)
>     {
>         return (list as IList<T>).Contains(source);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now lets compose a sample how to use it. We need entity class Note:
>
> ```
> public class Note
> {
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string NoteText { get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> Mapping configuration for it:
>
> ```
> public class NoteMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Note>
> {
>     public NoteMap()
>     {
>         // Primary Key
>         HasKey(t => t.Id);
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And our DbContext ancestor:
>
> ```
> public class MyContext : DbContext
> {
>     static MyContext()
>     {
>         DbInterception.Add(new FtsInterceptor());
>     }
>     public MyContext(string nameOrConnectionString) : base(nameOrConnectionString)
>     {
>     }
>     public DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
>     protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
>     {
>         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new NoteMap());
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Now we ready to use it. Lets search for 'john':
>
> ```
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         var s = FtsInterceptor.Fts("john");
>         using (var db = new MyContext("CONNSTRING"))
>         {
>             var q = db.Notes.Where(n => n.NoteText.Contains(s));
>             var result = q.Take(10).ToList();
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: How can I make it work with Database First approach?

Comment: Would also like to know how to get it to work with a Database First Approach

Comment: the link is broken is there an alternative link?

Comment: @user2279473 I updated the answer with the original content from webarchive

Comment: @MarianBan Thanks for you prompt response

Comment: For anyone using this, I had to change the search Regex to the following to make it work correctly with EF 6.4.4:  \[(\w*)\].\[(\w*)\]\s*LIKE\s*@(\w*)\s(?:ESCAPE N?'~')"

Answer (score 5):

You can use raw SQL queries with EF. So, there is another easy workaround.

```
        using (DBContext context = new DBContext())
        {
            string query = string.Format("Select Id, Name, Description From Fotos Where CONTAINS(Pesquisa, '\"{0}\"')", textBoxStrToSearch.Text);
            var data = context.Database.SqlQuery<Fotos>(query).ToList();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
```

Input validation etc. is omitted. 
Edit: Code is modified according to OP's query.