# How to use contains (T-SQL) in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, t-sql, entity-framework-6, contains

I am looking for the equivalent of this feature of T-SQL:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.users 
WHERE CONTAINS (name, 'Jack')
```

in Entity Framework.

Thanks.

P.S. "contains" in linq is equivalent of LIKE in TSQL (eg., '%jack%'). I'm not looking for this because this kind of search, especially on large databases may affect the performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CONTAINS` keyword is part of the full-text search capability in SQL Server - and as of this day, EF doesn't natively support full-text searching.

There are some approaches out there using EF "interceptors" or plain and simple T-SQL stored procedure to include this functionality into EF - but it's not part of the EF package provided by Microsoft.

See these other SO questions:

- [Entity Framework, Code First and Full Text Search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616304/entity-framework-code-first-and-full-text-search)
- [How to execute a full text search using entity framework 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25818516/how-to-execute-a-full-text-search-using-entity-framework-6/48339711))

Answer (score -1):

I think it's just `users.Where(x => x.name.Contains("jack"));`

Answer (score -1):

**In fact,** In SQL, it should be

```
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.users 
WHERE name like '%Jack%'
```

And in EF, It equals to

```
var result = dbContext.users.Where(p => p.name.Contains("Jack"))
```